# GRASS GIS tools cannot perform on QGIS 3.6 Noosa

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am a fresh-hand to QGIS 3.6 Noosa. When I want to use GRASS GIS tools like r.recode, r.cost and so on, I am confronted with error information like this:

> The specified GRASS 7 folder 'C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\bin' does not contain a
>   valid set of GRASS 7 modules. Please, go to the Processing settings
>   dialog, and check that the GRASS 7 folder is correctly configured.

I've checked the processing settings but still cannot find solution to this.

What should I do?

[image: error information]

[image: processing options]

Comment: Again a clear error message, go back to your installer and make sure you have installed grass 7

Answer (score 1):

Use the advanced installer. 
https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Download the applicable OSGeo4W Network Installer (64 bit) or (32 bit), depending on your system.

[image]

Double click to open the .exe file. I downloaded the 64 bit version, so mine is titled

> osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe

[image]

Follow the images.

[image]
[image]

Select the appropriate selection. I choose All Users.
[image]

Click next again.

[image]

Select the highlighted option.

[image]

Go through the list and install these items:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click next and also install all the other recommended modules, accept the agreements, Ts and Cs, and install.

When finished, find and open QGIS with Grass. The GRASS tools should run then.
[image]